# Is there any way to generate "fake" rows in MySQL result set?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need this for charting purposes. Basically i have to:

1. Select all sent SMS by date without time part, getting an array with dates/counts pairs day-by-day;
2. Add "fake" rows for days without any record in my table, that is filling all dates "gaps" with zeroes.

An example result and corresponding table (here simplified) would be:

```
array(
    '2012-05-26 00:00:00' => 1,
    '2012-05-27 00:00:00' => 0, // Fake added row
    '2012-05-28 00:00:00' => 2,
)

+----------------+----------------------+
| Table SMS | id | sent_at              |
+----------------+----------------------+
|           |  1 | 2012-05-26 21:58:41  |
+----------------+----------------------+
|           |  2 | 2012-05-28 22:19:21  |
+----------------+----------------------+
|           |  3 | 2012-05-28 02:19:21  |
+----------------+----------------------+
```

Is there any SQL command for doing this or should i do manually playing with PHP arrays?

Comment: What would be the reasoning behind this?

Comment: @ColeJohnson in some charting libraries you have to specify timestamps (x axis) and values (y axis) to get, say, a line chart. Since i'm storing only sent SMS i need to fill dates gaps.

Comment: what i do for this is in the while loop that creates the array, check the date is the next one from an array of date ranges, and insert as required.

Comment: I don't think you can manage without some code besides SQL since SQL is not Touring complete and you cannot have loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a UNION Statement

```sql
SELECT 
   sent_at,
   Count(*)
FROM (Select
        id,
        DATE(sent_at) as sent_at
      FROM TableName 
      Group by Date(sent_at)
      UNION ALL
      Select
        '0' as id,
        DATE('2012-05-27') as sent_at) derived_table
Group By sent_at
```

**Edited**

I suggested creating a special table to join against.

Creation of a datetable for querying

```sql
CREATE TABLE DateTable (
  DateValue DateTime,
  Year Int,
  Month Int,
  Day Int)
```

Now populate this table with all date values within the ranges you are querying.  You can easily join to this table with any valid date.  Allowing you to aggregate for Dates that do and do not exist.

Comment: Correct me if i wrong, but this would add just one row to the result set. I have to fill "gaps" between all dates.

Comment: @gremo  if you want to count all the specific dates then you will need to use a derived table with the "fake rows" you have added (which make up the gaps).  If you want to make the gaps fill dynamically I suggest you build out a date table for yourself, that will include all the dates for a specific timeframe.  Then join to this table to get the missing dates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do this all the time

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Example`;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `Example` (
    $StartDate DATE,
    $EndDate DATE
    )
BEGIN

    DECLARE $curDay DATE;
    SET $StartDate = IFNULL($StartDate,'2000-01-01');
    SET $curDay = $StartDate;


    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `Day`;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `Day`(
        `Date` DATE
    );

    DaysLoop:LOOP

        INSERT INTO
            `Day`(`Date`)
        SELECT 
            $curDay
        ;

        SET $curDay = $curDay + INTERVAL 1 DAY;

        IF 
            $curDay >= $EndDate OR $curDay >= NOW()
        THEN 
            LEAVE DaysLoop;
        END IF;

    END LOOP DaysLoop;

    SELECT
        D.Date,
        COUNT(S.id)
    FROM
        `Day` AS D
    LEFT JOIN
        `SMS` AS S
        ON D.Date = DATE(S.sent_at)
    GROUP BY
        D.Date
    ORDER BY
        D.Date
    ;

END $$

DELIMITER ;

CALL Example('2012-01-01','2012-05-01');
```

I use and recommend stored procedures for reports, just make sure you version control the create scripts and whatnot.

Comment: Oh and you don't have to have the `group by`, or it can be made to group by DAY_HOUR etc